# R: complete a dataset with a new column added

Tags: r, dataset

I have a dataset looks like this:

*(Visualising the datasets below may help you to understand the question)*

```
original <- data.frame(
  ID = c(rep("John", 4), "Steve"),
  A = as.integer(c(rep(3, 4), 1)),
  b = c(2, 3, 4, 2, 2),
  B = c(rep(4, 4), 2),
  detail1 = c("Yes", "Sure", "No", "Yes", "Yes"),
  detail2 = c(rep("Unique1", 4), "Unique2")
)
```

Values in `A`, `B`, and `b` are all integers. Variable `b` is incomplete in this dataset and it actually has values from 1 to the value of `B`.

I need to complete this dataset with a new variable `a` added, the completed dataset will look like this:

```
completed1 <- data.frame(
  ID = c(rep("John", 12), rep("Steve", 2)),
  a = c(rep(1, 4), rep(2, 4), rep(3, 4), rep(1, 2)),
  A = c(rep(3, 12), rep(1, 2)),
  b = c(rep(1:4, 3), 1, 2),
  B = c(rep(4, 12), rep(2, 2)),
  detail1 = c("Absence", "Yes", "Sure", "No", "Absence", "Yes", rep("Absence", 7), "Yes"),
  detail2 = c(rep("Unique1", 12), rep("Unique2", 2))
)
```

Values in  `a` are integers too and `a` has values from 1 to the value of `A`. **Note that** `b` **is nested in** `a`.

I think the most relevant functions to complete a dataset in this way are `tidyr::complete()` and `tidyr::expand()`, but they can only complete combinations of values in existing variables, they cannot add a new column(variable).

**I know the challenge is that there are multiple locations to allocate values in** `detail1` **correspondingly to values in the newly added** `a` **through the nested relationship**, for example, the completed dataset can also be this:

```
completed2 <- data.frame(
  ID = c(rep("John", 12), rep("Steve", 2)),
  a = c(rep(1, 4), rep(2, 4), rep(3, 4), rep(1, 2)),
  A = c(rep(3, 12), rep(1, 2)),
  b = c(rep(1:4, 3), 1, 2),
  B = c(rep(4, 12), rep(2, 2)),
  detail1 = c("Absence", "Yes", rep("Absence", 4), "Sure", "Absence", "Absence", "Yes", "Absence", "No", "Absence", "Yes"),
  detail2 = c(rep("Unique1", 12), rep("Unique2", 2))
)
```

I would like to complete the dataset following the logic of `completed1` above: values in `detail1` go to the smallest value in `a` first, and if repeated values in `b` present (for example, the `Yes` in `b` under `John` in `original` dataset), the repeated value goes to the next value in `a`.

Is it possible to do this?

My actual dataset has more variables than this example and the completed dataset will have more than 700,000 rows, so I prefer fast methods to automate it.

Thanks very much!!!

Comment: I think adding `a` is the easy part, `original %>%
  mutate(a = lapply(A, seq), b = lapply(B, seq)) %>%
  tidyr::unnest(a)` should do it just fine. I can think of a couple ways to do `b`, but they don't seem very good. I'll sleep on it and see if anything comes.

Comment: @GregorThomas much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please let me know if it's not following your purpose.

```
comp_dummy <- original %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  expand(A = A, a = 1:A, B = B, b = 1:B)


dummy <- original %>%
  group_by(ID, A,b,B, detail1) %>%
  mutate(a = 1:n())

  ID        A     b     B detail1 detail2     a
  <chr> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>   <chr>   <int>
1 John      3     2     4 Yes     Unique1     1
2 John      3     3     4 Sure    Unique1     1
3 John      3     4     4 No      Unique1     1
4 John      3     2     4 Yes     Unique1     2
5 Steve     1     2     2 Yes     Unique2     1

comp_dummy %>%
  full_join(dummy, by = c("ID","A","a","B","b")) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(detail2 = unique(detail2[!is.na(detail2)]),
         detail1 = replace_na(detail1, "Absence")) 

   ID        A     a     B     b detail1 detail2
   <chr> <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>   <chr>  
 1 John      3     1     4     1 Absence Unique1
 2 John      3     1     4     2 Yes     Unique1
 3 John      3     1     4     3 Sure    Unique1
 4 John      3     1     4     4 No      Unique1
 5 John      3     2     4     1 Absence Unique1
 6 John      3     2     4     2 Yes     Unique1
 7 John      3     2     4     3 Absence Unique1
 8 John      3     2     4     4 Absence Unique1
 9 John      3     3     4     1 Absence Unique1
10 John      3     3     4     2 Absence Unique1
11 John      3     3     4     3 Absence Unique1
12 John      3     3     4     4 Absence Unique1
13 Steve     1     1     2     1 Absence Unique2
14 Steve     1     1     2     2 Yes     Unique2
```

Comment: This is perfect thanks so much!!